# Adding controls with bindings to an Xamarin ListView at runtime?

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, listviewitem

I am attempting to add a label with binding to a ListView at runtime (basic example for StackOverflow purposes, this isn't something I can just add to the XAML ItemTemplate).

The issue I am running into is that if I add a label with a binding as so:

```
private void Cell_OnAppearing(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     View view = ((ViewCell) sender).View;
     StackLayout myStackLayout= (StackLayout)view.FindByName("myStackLayout");
     Label lblTest = new Label()
     {
          HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand,
          VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
          Text = "{Binding TestLabelText}"
     };
     myStackLayout.Children.Add(lblTest);
}
```

Rather than display the result of the binding the label just displays the text "{Binding TestLabelText}".

Is there a way to get this to work or alternatively to access the bound data for this ListView cell and set the Label text that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [SetBinding](http://Xamarin.Forms%20Basic%20Bindings) and potentially set the *context*

> - The `BindingContext` property specifies the source object.
> - The `SetBinding` method specifies the target property and source property.

**Example**

```
label.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "TestLabelText");
```

Another alternative, is just *xaml* the label at design time (where it can be precompiled), and change its visibility when needed.

<sub>***Note** : you need to be careful when changing the visual tree of a list item, there is a lot of caching and optimization done, changing the its size might cause you a problem*</sub>

Comment: Your answer worked perfectly thank you :-) Do you have any further info regarding the problems this may cause though please? Would hate to complete the app and then run into issues?

Comment: @Apqu take a read through this to see the cache strategies https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/performance

Comment: Brilliant, thank you so much for your help, very much appreciated